# How to send email from Symfony without running consume command?

Tags: php, symfony, email, mailer

I want to send email from Symfony 6.2. I followed the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/mailer.html) and made this code (gmail address is example, I'm using own domain name):

```php
$email = (new Email())
    ->from("from@gmail.com")
    ->to("go@gmail.com")
    ->subject("Here is my subject")
    ->html("<p>Here is the content</p>");

$mailer->send($email);
```

I also edit the file `.env`.

- I changed `MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN` from `doctrine://default?autosetup=false` to `doctrine://default`
- I added `MAILER_DSN=smtp://from%40gmail.com:mdp@ssl0.ovh.net`

And, actually it doesn't send email automatically, Symfony say they are queued. And it's right as it created the table with messages, put queued on them. I should use the command `php bin/console messenger:consume -vv async` and let it running to see email be sent.

Here is my `config/packages/messenger.yaml` file:

```yaml
framework:
    messenger:
        failure_transport: failed
        transports:
            async:
                dsn: '%env(MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN)%'
                options:
                    use_notify: true
                    check_delayed_interval: 60000
                retry_strategy:
                    max_retries: 3
                    multiplier: 2
            failed: 'doctrine://default?queue_name=failed'

        routing:
            Symfony\Component\Mailer\Messenger\SendEmailMessage: async
            Symfony\Component\Notifier\Message\ChatMessage: async
            Symfony\Component\Notifier\Message\SmsMessage: async
```

How can I make email be sent from php (or at least not necessary to use the command)?

Comment: I believe this is the new way Symfony processes mail via messenger. To send mail without messenger, go to *config/packages/messenger.yaml*  under `routing` comment out `Symfony\Component\Mailer\Messenger\SendEmailMessage: async`.

Comment: @Bossman I just added my `config/packages/messenger.yaml` file, and the line you're giving is already without comment

Comment: So have you commented it out so it is not used? You can comment it out by using `#`. Or you can remove the line altogether.

Comment: Oh ok, sorry @Bossman I didn't understand as I'm not english. I just tried and it works, thanks ! Can you make an answer that I can accept?

Comment: The idea behind this is that you have a cron that will periodically call this command

Comment: @johnSmith I understand the objective but it's not what I wanted. I prefer send the email right now. I already have multiple cron task and I want to reduce them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Symfony 6 now sends email via messenger queuing. This is a better approach, however if you would like to disable this functionality and send email directly, you can comment out (or remove) `Symfony\Component\Mailer\Messenger\SendEmailMessage: async` like so:

```yaml
# config/packages/messenger.yaml
routing:
    # Symfony\Component\Mailer\Messenger\SendEmailMessage: async
    Symfony\Component\Notifier\Message\ChatMessage: async
    Symfony\Component\Notifier\Message\SmsMessage: async
```