# How is Symfony's SendMailMessage asynchronous queue being processed?

Tags: symfony, email, asynchronous

I'm trying to add the password-reset-bundle to my Symfony 6.3 implementation with EasyAdmin 4.7, and the emails never get sent.  If Symfony now expects to have a SendMailMessage queued, as detailed in the answers to this question:
[text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75681408/how-to-send-email-from-symfony-without-running-consume-command)
can someone say how messages should be removed from the queue and dispatched?

I can get the emails sent by disabling the asynchronous queueing, but without executing the consume command from the console, they just sit in the queue forever.  Queueing email messages seems desirable from a performance perspective, but the current implementation in the reset-password-bundle does not seem to actually send them to the configured MAILER_DSN.